# how can i make the tabindex of the specific class every element to -1

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a loop over the code where i want to loop over the div and if there is any tab index on any element inside that div, i want it to be `-1` instead of `0`

i tried this code but its not working,

```
document.querySelector('.app-container-grid').forEach((grid,index) => {
        grid.setAttribute("tabindex", -1); 
      });
```

it just keeps the tabindex to whatever value it has and does it not change it to `-1`

Comment: Please add sample HTML to the question. Maybe your query selector is wrong.

Comment: My guess is that `.app-container-grid` matches the containers, not the inputs themselves. You need to use a selector that matches the inputs, maybe `.app-container-grid input[tabindex]`

Comment: You can't use `forEach` on a `querySelector` result, that is always a `Element`. use `querySelectorAll` instead. It returns an array-like object on which you can use `forEach`

Comment: @barmar tabindexis applied on div elements too, not only input fields, so have to consider that, also on svg

Comment: You should be getting an error in the console for the problem that @Apollo79 noticed. Didn't you see that in your debugging?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to loop over the div and if there is any tab index on any element inside that div

This will select all elements with a `tabindex` attribute inside `.app-container-grid` and changes the `tabindex` attribute to `"-1"`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.app-container-grid [tabindex]').forEach((element) => {
    element.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
});
```

Comment: Consider using the [`HTMLElement.tabIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/tabIndex) property instead of `setAttribute`

Comment: it still shows focus on the parent element when i open my dialog after adding that above code in computed

Comment: It only sets `tabindex` to child elements which have a `tabindex` attribute. Parent elements with a class of `app-container-grid` remain unchanged. Do the tabindexes get changed after the above code is run?

As @Barmar commented, it would be good to have sample HTML because this is the first time you've mentioned a dialog opening